# Generate specific permutation of binary array

Tags: javascript

I'm stuck at figuring out how to generate a specific permutation of a binary array.

Let's say I have a fixed length array of `n` elements. Each element can either be `0` or `1`. The total amount of permutations is `2^n`.

How can I generate a specific permutation `k` where `0 <= k < 2 ** n`?

It doesn't matter how the arrays are populated with ones and zeroes as long as the algorithm is deterministic and always returns the same array for each `k`.

Comment: do you have an example? what means `0 > k`? shouldn't it be `0 < k`?

Comment: "0 > k" you probably meant `0 <= k < 2 ** n`, or `0 < k <= 2 ** n`.

Comment: Just do a binary decode of the `int` value `k`.

Comment: A specific permutation `k` in this case is a binary number where 0 <= k < n^2. So do like `k.toString(2).padStart(n,"0")`.

Comment: @Redu Thanks, this seems to be the solution. Every number between 0 and 2 ** n has a unique binary representation which is exactly what I need. I was thinking way too hard about this…